# How to proper redirect old domain to new one with changed structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect an old domain to a new domain but at the same time I don't want the keep the exact structure and I'm afraid I might get into some redirect issues. Looking for some advice, if possible.

My old domain at its root has a software repository and in its /guides/ folder, a blog with articles. I want to redirect this domain to a new domain but swapping the redirects.

```
www.oldomain.com --> www.newdomain.com/software/
www.olddomain.com/guides --> www.newdomain.com
```

Since I have limited experience with redirects, should I redirect starting at the lower level then the top level?

I'm thinking about this:

```
RewriteRule ^olddomain.com/software/ ^newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^olddomain.com/ ^newdomain.com/software/ [R=301,L]
```

Is this the proper way of doing it?

Comment: This is somewhat strange... Is it correct that the host names with and without the "www." prefix should have different sematics?

Comment: As I know of, no...www is a subdomain so it should be handled ok with a wildcard if you want to include both www and non-www

Comment: From the point of view there is no such thing as a "domain", but only host names. Yes, name resolution can use wildcards _if that is configured_ , but that has nothing to do with the http server and also not with rewriting rules. The rules you suggest certainly will _not_ handle both host names automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
www.olddomain.com/guides --> www.newdomain.com
www.oldomain.com --> www.newdomain.com/software/
```

Check this rewrites in your olddomain.com .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^guides$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/software/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So in one case you _do_ check the requested host, in the other case _not_ ? Hmmmm

Comment: Isn't RewriteRule ^guides$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L] only redirect the /guides/ only? If the site has an article in /guides/article.html it won't work